# No prompt from JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code only gets me to link address but doesn't run the function. (the last `alert()` function doesn't run).

I need this alert, what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laboratorul nr_3</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script language="javascript"><!--
        function ex1()
            {
               num = prompt("Input the number");
                result = num * 3;
                alert(num + " x " + 3 + " = " + result);
                num2 = prompt("Input number to add");
                result2 = num * 3 + parseint(num2);
                alert(num + " x " + 3 + " + " num2 " = " + result2);
            }
    //--></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <a href="http://google.com" onclick="javascript:ex1()">link</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `alert(num + " x " + 3 + " + " num2 " = " + result2);` you forgot the `+` around `num 2`.

Comment: try to use a debugger to see the errors (like f12 on the firefox + firebug). Usually when the javascript doesn't prompt is from a typo or a misuse.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cancel the native action (following the link):

```
function ex1() {
    // code...
    return false;
}
```

Or use a different element that doesn't do anything, maybe a `<button>` or `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

There was only 3 errors you didn't call the function and you didn't concate the string and the parseInt, int cannot be spelled in lower case

```js
function ex1(){
  num = prompt("Input the number");
  result = num * 3;
  alert(num + " x " + 3 + " = " + result);
  num2 = prompt("Input number to add");
  result2 = num * 3 + parseInt(num2);
  alert(num + " x " + 3 + " + " + num2 +" = " + result2);
}

ex1()
```